# Android App Transfer Can't Find Transaction Id

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to transfer an app to a different account and it seems impossible to find my transaction id per the instructions here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en The problem is these instructions don't work. I can't find the id anywhere inside of that website. And the instructions "You can find this on the receipt that was emailed to you when you registered for each account." also are wrong. I made my account in 2012, I believe these only work for fairly recently made accounts as the older emails do not contain the transaction id and only have an order number.

I've found this id in the past and had written down my old instruction where I got it via https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/home#oneTimePurchase but that website also no longer exists and instead redirects you to pay.google.com

I've also seen tutorials talking about where you can find it in pay.google.com under Subscriptions & services -> Other Purchase Activity.
However, the "Other Purchase Activity" section also doesn't exist.

As far as I can tell it is currently impossible to find this value for an account made in 2012 (might be possible on newer accounts).

Does anyone have any working instructions as of today? Is it impossible to transfer apps now?

Comment: Did you find your transaction ID?

Comment: The same for me. Account has created in 2013. Waiting for response from google support team..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tried all the methods mentioned in [this post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/SVV7SAWs68s;context-place=forum/play). I don't think any more methods for getting the transaction ID exists. You should [Contact Google Play Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7100415#) for help.

**P.S :**

I see [your post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/play/PvtepRF4Iqc/fJXNrhROBwAJ;context-place=forum/play) in Google Support Forum. If this doesn't work, just Call/Email them and directly ask Transaction ID for your account. It will be resolved very fast.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up chatting with Google Pay chat support (Support.Google.com). I told them the order number, amount of money and date and they gave me back the ID.

Comment: We had taken free account during 2011. at that time account was free. what to do

Comment: Yeah, I also have such problem (account created in 2013). I posted request to support team 5 days ago, but no response yet

Comment: @brucemax we got same situation. did you got any response then?